# Multiple ADFS server with Identity server 4 in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, identityserver4, adfs

We are into data security and we have a portal which can be accessed through Azure AD. Now we want to add support for ADFS for login.

For this when we add new customer, we would ask for the details like ClientId, secret, call back URL etc and thinking to store this in our Web API table.

We use Identity server 4 for auth operations. If we want to add one or 2 ADFS servers, it would be easy as we can add the data we got from the customer and put it in a config and add those details in startup class hard coded. But if we would need to add new server, it would be extra work every time.

The Challenge we are facing is, we want to get ADFS server details from Web API database and the login page is in Identity server.

Should we call web api from startup or middle ware of identity server, which I guess is not the best option. Or we should have ADFS table at identity server side? This is challenge too as we add ADFS details from angular app which does not send anything back to identity server.

Can someone suggest best option for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are facing the issue because you have the database tied to your Web API. Conceptually, there is nothing a Web API database. You should never tie your databases with the application or APIs. Separate out your data logic into a separate project. Make it independent. Then that can be used from both your Web API as well as from your other Startup classes.